# PHP firebird insert blob file into the database apache suddenly stop working

Tags: php, apache, blob, firebird, interbase

I'm currently working on inserting image on the firebird database and it's working fine alone, see the code below.

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $user, $pass);

$blh = ibase_blob_create($dbh);   
ibase_blob_add($blh, $data);
$blobid = ibase_blob_close($blh);

$sql = "INSERT INTO blobtable(blobfield) VALUES (?)";  
$sth = ibase_query($dbh, $sql, $blobid);
```

but when I add some data on the insert statement suddenly the apache crash and stops working. See below code when I add new data.

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $user, $pass);

$blh = ibase_blob_create($dbh);   
ibase_blob_add($blh, $data);
$blobid = ibase_blob_close($blh);

$sql = "INSERT INTO blobtable(name, desc, blobfield ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";   
$sth = ibase_query($dbh, $sql, $name, $desc, $blobid);
```

Comment: im trying to insert blob into firebird database, im trying this code, but i cant understand what variable do you send as the blob. `blobfield` is what in that code? And what is your data? its the tmp_name?

Answer (score 3):

See the blob_create function in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/rowland/d59ee296f8be4b581fed

Probably your $data is larger than the maximum segment size.

Comment: thanks brent for the answer, I think it might be. the file size of my upload is 1mb and greater.