# how to import BLOB data to mysql

Tags: mysql, firebird

i have database firebird, one column use BLOB data type contain rtf

example

1. > {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
   >   Arial Narrow;}{\f1\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}
   >   \viewkind4\uc1\pard\sl240\slmult1\f0\fs18 Laki -laki    :    < 35 
   >   \par Wanita       :    < 31\f1\fs16\par }
2. > {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033\deflangfe1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0
   >   Arial Narrow;}{\f1\fnil MS Sans Serif;}}
   >       \viewkind4\uc1\pard\sl240\slmult1\f0\fs18 Laki -laki   :    <  41   \par
   >       Wanita      :    <  31\f1\fs16\par
   >       }

how do i import this database?, I'm tried export to csv then import to mysql workbench but the column become bigger because rtf value contain , and ;

Comment: maybe interesting? [PHP firebird insert blob file into the database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801781/php-firebird-insert-blob-file-into-the-database-apache-suddenly-stop-working)

Comment: @RyanVincent I have firebird database, export to csv, then from csv import to mysql. the problem my blob data in .csv contain , and ; so mysql workbench separate that blob data. that the reason why in mysql the column become bigger

Comment: have you tried: [FBExport : export and import data from Firebird databases](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/)? Other than that then, **imo**,  it is commercial stuff or _i would do:_ write your own using stuff using the 'odbc' driver (http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/)? PHP PDO works with `odbc`. I use windows so it is actually easy for me to use `odbc`. The `mysql` `blob` stuff is common and works everywhere.

Comment: As @RyanVincent says, there are "data pump" tools you can buy to do this (there are also open source solutions), or you could write this yourself using a language that has drivers for both database systems with blob support.